# Web Scrape from plain text into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, text

I need to web scrape http://www.bls.gov/schedule/schedule/2007/2007_sched.htm  for every Date that contains "The Employment Situation" under the "Release Name" column. The web scraping output should be:

```
Jan.  5, Feb.  2, 2007, March  9, April  6, May  4, June  1, 2007
July  6, 2007, Aug.  3, Sept.  7, Oct.  5, Nov.  2, 2007, Dec.  7  
#year can be ignored/omitted
```

To achieve the same for http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm, used the following:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_html("http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm")

# target only  <td> elements under bodytext div
body <- html_nodes(pg, "div#bodytext")

# use this new set of nodes and a relative XPath to get initial <td> elements, then get their siblings
es_nodes <- html_nodes(body, xpath=".//td[contains(., 'Employment Situation for')]/../td[1]")

# clean up and make dates
nfpdates <- as.Date(trimws(html_text(es_nodes)), format="%A, %B %d, %Y")
```

That stored the list of dates under `nfpdates`. I tried to adapt that code to work for http://www.bls.gov/schedule/schedule/2007/2007_sched.htm and failed. The issue is these two URLs store the information in different formats. How could the dates be extracted from that URL, given that the information is stored in plain text rather than in an HTML table? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the full solution but it does pull the requested lines containing "The Employment Situation" from the web page.  The text which you are requesting is associated with the pre tag.  On this page there are 4 sections (sections 3 & 4 are empty).

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/schedule/2007/2007_sched.htm"
body<-html_nodes(read_html(url), "pre")
#text= xml_text(body[1])  #only uses the first table
text= sapply(1:length(body), function(i) {xml_text(body[i])})  #looks at all tables
#create one list for all the captured lines
table1<-unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
#find lines that match the search string
employ<-table1[grepl("The Employment Situation", table1)]
```

The final result is:

> [1] "The Employment Situation, December 2006                         Jan.  5  \t 8:30 am\r"
> [2] "The Employment Situation, January 2007                         \tFeb.  2, 2007\t 8:30 am   \r"
>
> ...

At this point it is a matter of using strsplit, gsub, grep to clean up and isolate the desire text from each line.
If you are still having issues maybe another Stackoverflow question focusing on extracting the dates from each line.
Good luck.